# Expanding input box on input with CSS

Tags: css

I have been searching SO for a good answer for this specific question, however many of the answers are from 2012 or earlier and advances in CSS may already tackle this.

If I have an input box which is only one character wide (lets assume 8px) is there a way to have this box expand on user input to grow with the size of the input? I have tried using `contenteditable="true"` but this did not seem to take any effect with an input box.  Multiple attempts at adjusting the width did not take any effect.

Working out of this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3079afmk/9/)

**NOT A CSS SOLUTION**

But this is what I ended up doing with jquery

```
$("input").bind('keyup', function(){
        var inputLength = $(this).val().length
        if(inputLength > 0){
        $(this).attr("size", $(this).val().length)
        }
        else{
            $(this).attr("size", "1")
        }
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kzq4tcxb/2/)

Comment: Zach, your fiddle has syntax errors. Correct them and update your question

Comment: Must it be a CSS only solution?

Comment: It does not need to, I think i'm going to close this question out. I was simply inquiring if this has been solved with pure CSS. JS is just fine.

Comment: Zach, don't close it. It's a good challenge to find a CSS only solution to this (if even possible). A JS solution is easy though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some html element with `contenteditable` attribute, than grab its content on `input` event, check it out:

```js
$('[data-store]').each(function(i) {
    var thisContent = $(this);
    var remoteInput = $( thisContent.data('store') );
    thisContent.on('input', function(e) {
        remoteInput.val( $(this).text() );
        $('#current_value').text( remoteInput.val() );
    });
    
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
 padding: 0 5px;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 min-width: 5%;
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
[contenteditable]:focus,
[contenteditable]:hover {
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
[contenteditable] br {
 display: none;
}
[contenteditable] * {
 display: inline;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span maxlength="10" value="1" contenteditable="true" data-store="#yourtext"></span></p>
<input type="hidden" id="yourtext" name="yourtext" />
<p>The hidden input value: <b><span id="current_value"></span></b></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your .inputbox css a bit to this:

```
.inputbox {
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

As long as there are no spaces it should expand, you gave it a max-width which was part of the problem, telling it not to grow past a certain point. The display: inline-block so of expands/contracts based on the widest content.

Comment: chiapa, This was based on the original post and Zach changed to a different JSFiddle so it doesn't match anymore, it worked with whatever code he had originally.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the contenteditable attribute works on input fields. Any other element with this attribute works fine.

In my fiddle, I have made a div with content editable set to true. You can change the styles to make it look like an input box. And support both min-width of the input field and max-width

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  min-width: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3079afmk/2/

Comment: Unfortunately this element needs to be an input box, this I have no control over.  I may need to just write the JS to handle the expand.